# Do unrestricted unions require placement new and a constructor definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

The examples I've seen of unrestricted unions always seem to use placement new when constructing. The Wikipedia article for C++11 features uses placement new in the constructor of a union.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions

```
#include <new> // Required for placement 'new'.

struct Point {
    Point() {}
    Point(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y) {} 
    int x_, y_;
};

union U {
    int z;
    double w;
    Point p; // Illegal in C++03; legal in C++11.
    U() {new(&p) Point();} // Due to the Point member, a constructor definition is now required.
};
```

Is it necessary to use placement new here? For example, this piece of code compiles without warnings with gcc and valgrind shows no memory leaks when the union is used to hold a string:

```
struct HasUnresUnion
{
    enum { Int, String } tag;

    HasUnresUnion(int i)
      : tag(Int),
        as_int(i)
    {}

    HasUnresUnion(std::string str)
      : tag(String),
        as_str(std::move(str))
    {}

    ~HasUnresUnion()
    {
        using std::string;
        if (tag == String)
            as_str.~string();
    }

    union
    {
        int as_int;
        std::string as_str;
    };
};
```

It doesn't seem like there's any ambiguity here so I don't see why the standard would outlaw this. Is this legal code? Is placement new necessary when the union is *uninitialized* (rather than being assigned to)? Is the constructor in the union required? I've definitely seen unrestricted unions without their own constructors but Wikipedia explicitly states it's required.

Comment: Just a somewhat related note: A constructor initializer list could be used as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Isn't the OP doing just that? (Or, at least, asking whether it is allowed.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't understand the comment. :( The code uses a member initializer list.

Comment: You *structure* uses it, but you could use it for the union constructor as well. No need for placement new. I don't know if it's really allowed by the specification (don't have it "on me" right now), but I don't see why not. A constructor is a constructor is a constructor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah, gotcha. I just feel weird about giving my unions member functions but even if the union had a ctor the question would be the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Introduction

The snippet you have shown is perfectly safe; you are legally allowed to initialize **one** non-static data-member when initializing your *union-like class*.

---

#### Example

The wikipedia article has an example where *placement-new* is used because they are writing to a member after the point in which it is possible to directly initialize a certain member.

```
union A {
   A () { new (&s1) std::string ("hello world"); }
  ~A () { s1.~basic_string<char> (); }
  int         n1;
  std::string s1;
};
```

The previous snippet is however semantically equivalent to the following, where we explicitly state that `A::s1` shall be initialized when constructing `A`.

```
union A {
   A () : s1 ("hello world") { }
  ~A () { s1.~basic_string<char> (); }
  int         n1;
  std::string s1;
};
```

---

#### Elaboration

In your snippet you have an *anonymous union* inside your class (which makes your class a *union-like class*), which means that unless you initialize **one** of the members of the `union` during initialization of the class — you must use *placement-new* to initialize them at a later time.

---

#### What does the Standard say?

> ```
> 9.5/1 -- Unions -- [class.union]p1
> ```
>
> > In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any 
> >     time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can 
> >     be stored in a union at any time.

> ```
> 3.8/1 -- Object lifetime -- [basic.life]p1
> ```
>
> > [...]
> >     The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
> >
> > - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> > - if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.
> >
> > The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
> >
> > - if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> > - the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

Answer (score 1):

No, placement new is not required here. The standard says that in case of unrestricted unions, the field constructors should be called explicitly, otherwise the fields will be uninitialized.

You can call the constructor using traditional way

```
U(): p() {}
```

and exotic way

```
U() { new(&p) Point(); }
```

The second variant may be useful if it is not possible to construct the field before calling the constructor of `U`.

Don't also forget about placement destructors in this case.

Comment: Does the union itself require a constructor? Is something like the example I gave legal?

Comment: Yes, it requires an explicitly defined constructor if any of the union fields contains non-trivial special member functions. Yes, the code seems legal. But you can be handcutted if you use this code in real projects.

Comment: Placement delete? Usually the analogue to placement new is just manually calling the destructor.

Comment: Yes, I meant destructors