# std::variant with const arguments in C++

Tags: c++, variant

There is a nice unanswered question about having union with `const` members: [Can you write a copy constructor for a union with const members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658144/can-you-write-a-copy-constructor-for-a-union-with-const-members)

One of suggestions there is to use `std::variant` instead. Indeed, const types must be supported [P0086 - Variant design review](http://wg21.link/p0086). The relevant paragraph says:

> `variant<int, const int>` A `variant` can handle `const` types: they
> can only be set through `variant` construction and `emplace()`.

So I assume `variant` copy construction must support them as well.

But an attempt to use this option:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using S = std::variant<const int, const std::string>;

int main() {
    S s(1);
    S u = s;

    S v("abc");
    S w = v;
}
```

fails in GCC with a very long error (quote only its beginning here):

```
n file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211024/include/c++/12.0.0/variant: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<_First, _Rest ...>::_Variadic_union(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 1; _Args = {const int&}; _First = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Rest = {}]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211024/include/c++/12.0.0/variant:409:4:   required from 'constexpr std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<_First, _Rest ...>::_Variadic_union(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = 2; _Args = {const int&}; _First = const int; _Rest = {const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20211024/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/stl_construct.h:119:7:   required from 'constexpr void std::_Construct(_Tp*, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<const int, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >; _Args = {const std::in_place_index_t<2>&, const int&}]'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ocajj3aao

Is there something wrong with my code, or GCC must accept it?

Comment: The problem appeared after [libstdc++ implemented P2231R1](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/ad820b0bb5f8342a8db2831d1f15c103583a3ba0#diff-42d34e2570773e3c256c114cc9371f613ed6fbb68be254f3ab008d872d630c6b), I very much suspect that this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, the code only started to be rejected by GCC trunk very recently (and is accepted by all released versions of GCC), after I implemented [P2231R1](https://wg21.link/p2231r1).

As I said in the [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102912), before P2231R1 the libstdc++ `std::variant` was playing a bit fast and loose with constructing the active member of the union. After the P2231 changes we need to construct the correct union member, or it won't be valid in `constexpr` functions. That required some refactoring to be able to use the index of the member when constructing it.

It's fixed now, thanks for noticing the bug.