# Is `reinterpret_cast` on `this` inside union-like class an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct B {
    uint32_t c() {
        uint32_t * value = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(this);
        return * value;
    }
};

struct A {
    union {
        B b1;
        B b2;

        uint32_t a { 10 };
    };
};

int test() {
    A a;
    return a.b1.c();
}
```

Here `test()` returns 10 because all A is a union-like struct. My question is, assuming A satisfies [StandardLayoutType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) concept, is casting `this` inside `B::c` to get pointer to a `A::a` undefined behavior?

Comment: This `return * value;` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Accessing a non-active member of a union is always UB in C++

Comment: Why do not you use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: @Boiethios I'm not implementing variant container — I'm experimenting with well-defined bitfield access

Comment: @JohnDoe I just wanted to say that there is no reason to use `union` in modern C++ while `variant` exists.

Comment: @Boiethios I understand that. My idea was to make B template class and implement methods for bitfield access. These methods would access actual integer value by casting `this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. As an overview the union contains either a `uint32_t` or a `B`.

- If it's a `B` then the cast is illegal (since it's not a `uint32_t` you mustn't cast to it).
- If it is a `uint32_t` then calling the `.c()` member is illegal since you can't access the `b1` member (isn't the active union member).

In this case (thanks to [@StoryTeller's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) comment) the active union member is `a` (the `uint32_t`) since it's the only one with default initialization, thus calling `a.b1.c()` is UB.

Comment: It is initialized on account of that default member initializer. Not that it helps much with all the other UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I'm not up to date on the rules regarding union members with constructors, does this mean that both `b1` and `b2`'s constructors are run? In this case, which is the active member? I know that non-POD members to unions have been added to C++ but I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: @StoryTeller, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764531/3848) I'm not sure you're right.

Comment: No, they aren't run. `A a;` will attempt to do default initialization. Colloquially, since there is only one member with a default member initializer, that's the "default active member". If the default member initializer is removed, then `b1` will be initialized as thought by an empty pair of braces (`{}`), since it's of a trivial type. And that answer is irrelevant here. All the members of the union are of trivial types. The default constructor is not defined deleted (if it was, the program in the OP would not even build, let alone have UB).

Comment: Can I get rid of UB if I remove default constructor, assuming that `B` will not have any data members?

Comment: Actualy the cast is perfectly legal. The only illegal things is the second class member access in a.b.c().

Comment: @JohnDoe No you can not, because in the expression `(a.b).c()` `a.b` is evaluated, so `b` is accessed (its value is read) out of its lifetime (as long as we consider that evaluate means access see the footnote in the standard) see [\[expr.ref\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/expr.ref#1)