# Can a structure with union members be qualified as POD?

Tags: c++, unions

Can this structure MyWrapStruct:

```
struct MyWrapStruct
{
    bool myBool;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            void* myPtr;
            int myInt;
        };
        Struct1 myStruct1;
        Struct2 myStruct2;
    } myStructs;
};
```

With "sub-structures" :

```
struct Struct1
{
    void* myPtr;
    int myInt;
    float mySpecialFloat;
};

struct Struct2
{
    void* myPtr;
    int myInt;
    int mySpecialInt;
};
```

Be considered a POD structure?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it? Unions come from C, any traditional C structure is POD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - even union types merely contains data, and no methods, constructors, etc.

See:

[What are POD types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

**Update**
Provided, of course, the union only contains POD types.

See:

[Questions regarding C++ non-POD unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764150/questions-regarding-c-non-pod-unions)